# AHK: How to store the string "Brasília é do coração..." in a variable without losing the accents in autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey, str-replace, diacritics

I have thoroughly searched for this aweful ahk remarked limitation. If you copy the text and use the clipboard it works fine, but if you declare var:="Brasília é do coração..." it stores "BrasÃ­lia Ã© do coraÃ§Ã£o...".

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your ahk file is saved using the proper encoding. If you are using notepad++ to edit your ahk file you need to change the encoding to something other than ANSI or UTF-8. Alternatively, you can save it using Notepad.exe to get the proper encoding.